# jQuery mouse click counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, mouseevent

I need to color a table in zebra style, and then when I click on the table, twice (not double click), it should change back to original.

My question is, how to count 2 clicks?

Comment: declare a variable as counter and increase it by 1 on click, and check this counter value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aztVY/

```
(function () {
  var count = 0;

  $('table').click(function () {
    count += 1;

    if (count == 2) {
      // come code
    }
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function for that:

```
$(" ... ").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("someClass");
});
```

When clicked once, the element has the `someClass` class, and when clicked twice, the class is removed again.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but in between the lines of your question I read that you actually ask about `toggleClass()` method documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched  elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the  switch argument.